# Получение информации о базе данных / о таблице (нпр. размер таблицы) через EntityFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core

Нужно **получить информацию о самой таблице в Базе данных**, например, узнать, сколько в ней строк, столбцов. Или вовсе узнать количество таблиц в Базе данных или все их имена. Можно это всё **сделать напрямую средствами фреймворка**, вроде `int n = Магия.КоличествоСтрок(Таблица)`?

И если нельзя напрямую, как это **можно сделать косвенно**?
На ум из-за отсутствия опыта приходит только ввести в таблицу столбец с порядковым номером и в коде получать значение порядкового номера последнего элемента, что будет равно количеству строк. Или просто пересчёт ненулевых строк в таблице.

*Если это важно, работаю с WPF на .net 5.0 в связке c entity framework, БД на MicrSQL Server.*

Comment: Вы делаете что-то странное, есть большая вероятность что это проблема XY. Опишите подробнее зачем вам это нужно

Comment: @АндрейNOP Одна из простейших задач - отобразить N кнопок, каждая из которых названа полем соответствующей строки из таблицы размера N в БД. При том, что лично мне неизвестно N.
Код должен сперва понять, сколько строк в таблице, после сделать столько же кнопок, выдавая им название из бд.

Comment: Количество строк в таблице: `context.TableName.Count()`

Comment: EntityFramework - это ORM - маппер. В целом он не предназначен для того, что вы спрашиваете. Используйте обычные sql-запросы.

Comment: Когда то баловался подобным [Получение количества строк в каждой таблице базы данных](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/blog-post.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как Вам ответил @Alexander Petrov в комментариях, используйте обычные sql-запросы. Для Вашей задачи подойдет [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/relational-databases/system-information-schema-views/system-information-schema-views-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), например:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_NAME = 'имя_вашей_таблицы'
```

**UPD:**

Прошу прощения за невнимательность, строк, а не столбцов.

```
select COUNT(*) from 'имя_вашей_таблицы'
```